# Wordpress as a CMS, calling content Issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So I am working on my first wordpress site...

I am having a go at converting http://www.benjaminpotter.org/fleet/
to wordpress > http://www.benjaminpotter.org/test/

So there are already a few issues, but one of the things is that I am wanting to call content into the "about us" section on the index page via wordpress to act as a CMS.

This is an image of the back end:

[image]

nevertheless it ends up with no content in that section:

[image]

this is most likely because I need to put in a bit of code into the page of the website.

This is the current code for that page, and I have commented where I want to call the content mannaged bit... thanks for the help!

```
<? /* Template Name: Home Page
*/ ?>


<?php get_header(); ?> 





  <div id="tagline"></div>

    <div id="sliderbox">

        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/index/slider/slider_1.jpg" width="1000" height="466" alt="Don't settle for less" />

        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/index/slider/slider_2.jpg" width="1000" height="466" alt="Don't settle for less" />

        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/index/slider/slider_3.jpg" width="1000" height="466" alt="Don't settle for less" />

        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/index/slider/slider_4.jpg" width="1000" height="466" alt="Don't settle for less" />

  </div>

    <a id="arrow2" class="arrow"></a>

    <a id="arrow1" class="arrow"></a>

    <a href="order.php" id="car_logo_slider" onmouseover="tooltip.show('');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">

        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/index/car_slider/cars1.jpg" width="1001" height="86" alt="cars" />

        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/index/car_slider/cars2.jpg" width="1001" height="86" alt="cars" />

        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/index/car_slider/cars3.jpg" width="1001" height="86" alt="cars" />

    </a>

<div id="wrapper-contunue">

<div id="mission_vision_header"></div>

        <? include('inc/quickcontact.html'); ?>

        <div id="mission_vision_text">

            <!-- THE CONTENT MANAGED BIT! -->
            <!-- THE CONTENT MANAGED BIT! -->
            <!-- THE CONTENT MANAGED BIT! -->
            <!-- THE CONTENT MANAGED BIT! -->
            <!-- THE CONTENT MANAGED BIT! -->

        </div>

        <div style="margin-top:450px;" class="seperator"></div>

        <div id="our_process" class="highlighed_div">

            <div id="our_process_header"></div>

            <div id="initial_text_our_process">

            Here at Fleet Avenue, we have a simple and straight forward process towards acquiring our cars for you. This four step process is fast and effective, consisting of the following steps:

            </div>

            <div id="our_process_stages_graphic"></div>

            <div id="explanatiory_text_our_process">

                <div id="process_inquire">

                    <a id="inquire_button" href="order.php"></a>

                </div>


            </div> <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I'm exactly familiar with Wordpress software, but I imagine you'll have to dig around in the source to figure out how Wordpress figures out what elements to write to. This looks like static copy, though, have you thought about just adding it in manually?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo get_content(); ?>
```

Or

```
<?php
global $post;
echo $post->post_content;
?>
```

Comment: get_content() didn't work, along with get_the_content()... no idea why. The 2nd method works... but seems like an old method and also disregards some of the formatting within the wordpress CMS. Any other ideas?

Comment: global $post;the_content($post->ID);

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to wrap you call to the_content() in the Wordpress loop

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_content();
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

this is a very basic example if you make other calls later you will need to reset the query call after this one.

more info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop